# change return key type of last dynamic generated textfield

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am generating 4 dynamic UITextField all with return key type next and when i press next the focus gets transferred to next UITextField but what i want is when 4th UITextField gets focus its return key type must change to `Done` which when pressed must resign first responder.

for implementing `"next"` functionality i am using this code

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = [Feilds1Array indexOfObject:textField];
        if(currentIndex>=Feilds1Array.count-1)
        {

            NSLog(@"change return key type...");
        }
        else
        {
            UITextField* nextTextField1 = (UITextField*)Feilds1Array[currentIndex+1] ;
            [nextTextField1 becomeFirstResponder] ;
        }
```

this might be an easy one but i am not able to figure this out as i am a newbie
so please help me out
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

In your textField delegate method,

access the 4th textfield by using tag value or as you did already,

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if([textField isEqual:textField4]) 
         textField4.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if([textField isEqual:textField4]) 
         [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

Comment: textfeilds are generated as a group(in for loop) not individually

Comment: what problem then, just set its return key as I mentioned in answer while creating the textfields.

Comment: the first three textfeilds must have return key "Next and fourth one must have return key type "Done"..

Comment: @Chocolate.. Where you are creating your textfield put your code here

Answer (score 0):

If your text field is generated by xib in that case you need to set return key of last text field in your xib `Done`. See in the below image

[image]

other wise

```
NSUInteger currentIndex = [Feilds1Array indexOfObject:textField];
        if(currentIndex>=Feilds1Array.count-1)
        {

            NSLog(@"change return key type...");

             UITextField* nextTextField1 = (UITextField*)Feilds1Array[currentIndex+1] ;
             nextTextField1.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
             [nextTextField1 becomeFirstResponder] ;
        }
        else
        {
            UITextField* nextTextField1 = (UITextField*)Feilds1Array[currentIndex+1] ;
            [nextTextField1 becomeFirstResponder] ;
        }
```

Comment: the text feilds are generated through code not through xib and those textfeilds are group(using for loop) not individual

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating `UITextField` dynamically then you can set the property as

```
textfieldName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

in your case you can set the above property to the 4th textfield.